# iPadOS Where has Find Friends gone?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone, geolocation, ipados, find-my

I just updated my iPad to iPadOS13.1.2 and can't find some of my apps.

I used to use Find Friends - but it seems to be missing in action.
I can't even figure out how to search on the iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is renamed “Find My” and you can use Siri to locate it if your spotlight search is messed up or just updating after the update.

Not all of Apple’s documentation online is updated yet, but here’s a great starter if the Guide app that ships with iOS 13 doesn’t help you enough:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210400

Answer (score 1):

On your iPad go to Settings. When the Settings panel opens go to your name, which should be at the top left side, and click on that area. This opens a new panel on the right with your name at the top. About 7 lines down you see the line 'Find My'. This used to be Find My Friends.